# gcloud compute instances create command fails when creating an instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

Creating an instance using `gcloud` does not seem to work: 

`google-cloud> gcloud compute instances create minecraft-instance --image ubuntu-14-10 --tags minecraft
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Unable to fetch a list of zones. Specifying [--zone] may fix this issue:
 - Project marked for deletion.`

Adding the zone name fails differently:

`google-cloud> gcloud compute instances create minecraft-instance --image ubuntu-14-10 --zone us-central1-a --tags minecraft 
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Failed to find image for alias [ubuntu-14-10] in public image project [ubuntu-os-cloud].
 - Project marked for deletion.`

Providing a different image name fails too:

`google-cloud> gcloud compute instances create minecraft-instance --image ubuntu-1410-utopic --zone us-central1-a --tags minecraft 
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch image resource:
 - Project marked for deletion.`

What is the exact command to create an instance using `gcloud`?

Answer (score 9):

Did you authenticate before and set the default project?

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project PROJECT
```

The base setup of gcloud is in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/).

Or did you delete your project?

> Project marked for deletion.

Answer (score 5):

You have several things going on, one of which is reading the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#creating

You syntax should be:

```
gcloud compute instances create minecraftinstance \
--image ubuntu-14-10 \
--zone [SOME-ZONE-ID]  \
--machine-type [SOME-MACHINE-TYPE]
```

Where SOME-ZONE-ID is a geographic zone to create the instance in, found by running:

```
gcloud compute zones list
```

SOME-MACHINE-TYPE is the machince type to create. Valid types are found by running:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list
```

But specifically, you seem to be creating an instance in a Project that has been deleted:

> - Project marked for deletion.

Also, you need to authenticate and set a default project:

```
gcloud auth
```

and

```
gcloud config set project [ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

Billable resources can not be created for projects which has been flagged for deletion. For a project to be deletable, billing must be disabled first, and so, instances can not be created.  As for the error messages, it seems gcloud command is not handling this situation correctly and replying bogus error codes instead.

The only compulsory arguments to `gcloud compute instances create` are the name, the zone and the project. A valid working project must be set either by using `--project PROJECT` flag to gcloud commands, or by using `gcloud config set project PROJECT` before. Similarly, to choose the zone you can either use the `--zone ZONE` flag or the `gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE` command before.

Enabling billing on your current project and undeleting it will work too. To figure out which project and zone the gcloud command is running in by default, use this:

```
gcloud config list
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to specify `--image-project` that got me going:

```
gcloud compute instances create core --image ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20180126 --machine-type f1-micro --zone us-east4-a --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

My Case,Create a managed instance group using the instance template:

```
 gcloud compute instance-groups managed create nginx-group \
     --base-instance-name nginx \
     --size 2 \
     --template nginx-template \
     --target-pool nginx-pool \
      --zone us-central1-c
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the --image-project --image-family
Refer https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support.